# jq with single quotes bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jq

I tried to use bash to run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

myvar="data1"
data='[
  {
    "resource_name": "data1.something",
    "resource_type": "Topic"
  },
  {
    "resource_name": "data2.something",
    "resource_type": "Topic"
  }
]'
query=$(echo ".[] | select((.resource_type==\"Topic\") and (.resource_name | startswith(\"${myvar}\") | not))")
echo ${data} | jq ${query}
```

It doesn't work becasue of line :

```
echo ${data} | jq ${query}
```

But if I run the same script in zsh, it works. and gives me the following error:

```
jq: error: Could not open file |: No such file or directory

jq: error: Could not open file select((.resource_type=="Topic"): No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file and: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file (.resource_name: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file |: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file startswith("data1"): No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file |: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file not)): No such file or directory
```

I was unable to understand what exactly is the issue here, I can only think that I somehow need to add single quotes when using with bash.

For example, if I use single quotes:

```
echo ${data} | jq \'${query}\'
```

it gives an error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

'.[]
jq: 1 compile error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `--arg` option to import content as variables is preferred over injecting shell variables into the actual filter code. This also saves you from dealing with single or double quotes.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

myvar="data1"
data='[
  {
    "resource_name": "data1.something",
    "resource_type": "Topic"
  },
  {
    "resource_name": "data2.something",
    "resource_type": "Topic"
  }
]'
query='.[] | select((.resource_type==$type) and (.resource_name | startswith($var) | not))'
echo "${data}" | jq --arg type "Topic" --arg var "${myvar}" "${query}"
```

```json
{
  "resource_name": "data2.something",
  "resource_type": "Topic"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cK1kPzR9I7)

Comment: thanks, that actually clearer ;)